# Manta SV caller: I can't find a file in the path specified by the user guide

Tags: fusions

I trying to locally reproduce a [Manta](https://github.com/Illumina/manta) run as seen in the *log* of an illumina basespace [RNA-Seq Alignment tool v1.1.1](https://emea.illumina.com/products/by-type/informatics-products/basespace-sequence-hub/apps/rna-seq-alignment.html) run I've done. The log reads as follows:

```
[LOG][2021-03-12 20:58:56.377]03/12/2021,20:58:56.193,Launch process:  \
/path_to_RNA_Tools/bin/python  \
'/path_to_RNA_Tools/Manta/bin/configManta.py'  \
--rna --normalBam='path_to_alignments/alignments.bam' \
--runDir='path_to_samples/CTR/replicates/CTR/MantaFusions/manta.run'  \
--referenceFasta='/path_to_genomes/genome.fa' \
--config '/opt/illumina/Isis/2.6.25.18/Workflows/WholeGenomeRnaSeqWorker/scripts/configManta.py.ini'
```

The file shown in the line above `configManta.py.ini` is however no were to be found.
The [Manta user guide](https://github.com/Illumina/manta/blob/master/docs/userGuide/README.md#advanced-configuration-options) states in the linked section

> Options listed in the file: `${MANTA_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/configManta.py.ini`

The `configManta.py` is in the expected directory, only the `configManta.py.ini` is absent.

I am using [Manta version  1.6.0 from bioconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/manta).

Your insights will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--config` file option for Manta can be used to override the defaults in the global config file. If you type `configManta.py -h`, you'll see where the global config file has been installed. For me, it's here:

```
/home/steve/miniconda3/envs/manta/share/manta-1.6.0-1/bin/configManta.py.ini
```

So the command in your log file takes a specific config file installed into:

```
/opt/illumina/Isis/2.6.25.18/...
```

I suspect 'Isis' is a reference to Illumina's analysis tool 'IsisRNA'. Papers that mention Illumina's 'RnaReadCounter' tool, say that it is part of the *internal* analysis tool 'IsisRNA'. Because it's one of Illumina's in-house tools, I think you'd need to contact Illumina support to get a copy. I would only do this though if you need to reproduce *exactly* as per the command in your log file. If you only need to roughly reproduce the output, the defaults in the global config file are probably fine.